# sprockets - multiple entry points?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets

[Sprockets official documentation](http://getsprockets.org/installation_and_usage) clearly says that:

```
Sprockets takes any number of source files and preprocesses them
line-by-line in order to build a `single` concatenation.
```

I'm a big fan of sprockets in Rails but here's the problem - my application has to support multiple layouts(desktop browsers) and mobile clients(iphone, ipad, android phones etc).

Both of this layouts require their own HTML reset CSS rules. Concatenated rules of desktop&mobile reset files would make a conflict because they override low level CSS directives.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get multiple top-level CSS files by making a Sprocket file for each. For example, say you want `desktop.css` to be comprised of `reset.css`, `common.css`, and `ie.css` and `mobile.css` to be comprised of `common.css` and `ios.css`. You would have the following files:

- `app/assets/stylesheets/desktop.css`
- `app/assets/stylesheets/mobile.css`
- `app/assets/stylesheets/reset.css`
- `app/assets/stylesheets/common.css`
- `app/assets/stylesheets/ie.css`
- `app/assets/stylesheets/ios.css`

In `desktop.css`, you would have the following:

```
/*
 *= require reset.css
 *= require common.css
 *= require ie.css
 */
```

In `mobile.css`, you would have the following:

```
/*
 *= require common.css
 *= require ios.css
 */
```

Then, in `app/views/layouts/desktop.html.erb`, you would do

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :desktop, :debug => Rails.env.development? %>
```

and similarly for `mobile.html.erb`.

Lastly, you'll need to set the precompiled asset list in `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile = %w( desktop.css mobile.css )
```

Comment: Its worth noting here that adding scss/coffee files to the precomile list will NOT WORK! (And throw no error, either!).  You must name only with the .js/css extension.

Comment: For me, deleting the duplicate name files with scss/coffee.js files worked for me. 
Thanks @PeterEhrlich

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure if sprockets supports this but I know that if you use the [Jammit](http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/) gem. You can setup different packages each with it's own cocktail of your JS or css files. e.g. have a :workspace package for desktop and and :mobile package for mobiles. 
It is all defined in a config yaml file and it will concat them in the order you list them, which can help get plugin dependencies correct etc.

```
javascripts:
  workspace:
    - public/javascripts/vendor/jquery.js
    - public/javascripts/lib/*.js
    - public/javascripts/views/**/*.js
    - app/views/workspace/*.jst

  mobile:
    - public/javascripts/vendor/jquery.js
    - public/javascripts/lib/mobile.js


stylesheets:
  common:
    - public/stylesheets/reset.css
    - public/stylesheets/widgets/*.css
  workspace:
    - public/stylesheets/pages/workspace.css
  mobile:
    - public/stylesheets/pages/mobile.css
```

Jammit might be worth a look for your needs

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you already have different layouts for each device or device group.  If so, just include a different top-level css file in each, then have different require statements in those top-level files.  If you're using Rails 3.1, there's no reason you have to keep the built-in line that includes all css files.

Comment: I failed trying to use "different top-level css file" because it always force me to use single one.